# Approximate solution of $\Gamma(x+a)=k\, \Gamma(x+1)$ for $0 \leq x \leq a$

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, approximation, gamma-function

As the title says, I am looking for good approximate solution of the equation
$$\Gamma(x+a)=k\, \Gamma(x+1) \qquad \text{for} \qquad  0 \leq x \leq a$$ for a given real and positive value of $a$ and $k>0$.

This does not make much problems for a numerical point of view if we consider that the problem is to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log (\Gamma (x+a))-\log (\Gamma (x+1)) -\alpha \qquad\qquad \alpha=\log(k)$$ but the calculations are not cheap in terms of computer resources.

So, what I am looking is a good approximation $x_0$ of the solution such that, using Newton method,
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{\log (\Gamma (x_0+a))-\log (\Gamma (x_0+1)) -\alpha }{\psi (x_0+a)-\psi (x_0+1) }$$ be almost the exact solution (say within less than $0.1$% error).

After several attempts, I rescaled the problem using $x=at$ and looked for the zero of function
$$g(t)=\frac{\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (a (t+1))}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (a t+1)}\right)}{\log
   \left(\frac{\Gamma (2 a)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (a+1)}\right)}-\beta$$ where now $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \beta \leq 1$ (this looks to be more convenient).

Surprising ot not, all the curves are quite similar and "look" more or less like $t^{\gamma(a)}$. For illustration
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & \gamma(a) \\
 10 & 0.628739 \\
 20 & 0.608322 \\
 30 & 0.599442 \\
 40 & 0.594307 \\
 50 & 0.590907 \\
 60 & 0.588466 \\
 70 & 0.586617 \\
 80 & 0.585162 \\
 90 & 0.583983 \\
 100 & 0.583006
\end{array}
\right)$$

which were obtained minimizing with respect to $\gamma$
$$\Phi_a(\gamma)=\large{\int_0^1} \Bigg[\frac{\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (a (t+1))}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (a t+1)}\right)}{\log
   \left(\frac{\Gamma (2 a)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (a+1)}\right)}-x^{\gamma}\Bigg]^2\,dt$$

Based on these values, a quick and dirty regression gave
$$\gamma(a) \sim \frac{\frac{349}{494}+\frac{90}{1087} a } {1+\frac{101}{701} a}$$ which is more than empirical but which works decently $(R^2>0.999999)$

For illustration, using  $a=45.678$ and $\beta=0.7654$, Newton method gives as iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 0.592046 \\
 1 & 0.611257 \\
 2 & 0.611455
\end{array}
\right)$$ wich achieves the goal but at the price of a too high empiricism.

So, **my question**

> Is there any way to better approximate $x_0$ or $\gamma(a)$ based on rigourous mathematics ?

Comment: Bonjour Claude! By curiosity, what is the origin of the problem? Something practical... or just for the fun?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net. Curiosity being the strict opposite of a sin, I shall answer. This equation is an approximation of somethinga bit more complex which appears in a theoretical research work of mine in the area of statistical themodynamics and simultion in the grand canonical ensemble.

Comment: Try Gautschi's inequality.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea. Already done (for sure)

Comment: Hi Claude.  Initial thought. We may write your problem as $(x)_a-kx=0$ where $(s)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol. In the special case $a\in\Bbb N$ this reduces to solving for the root of a polynomial of degree $\min\{a,1\}$ (see [Eqn. (8) here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html)).

Comment: My previous comment should read $\max\{a,1\}$ not $\min\{a,1\}$.